# Editor for HMIs in Java

Tags: java, user-interface, diagram, scada

I found this question [Creating SCADA diagrams in .NET](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1159349) and mine is roughly the same, except, that I need a Java version.

What I would need, is a editor which can be used standalone to create the GUI. It should support some kind of abstraction of datasources and data items which can be bound to the symbols placed on the view. It must be able to create symbols/components which may consist of other symbols/components and have some way to define the dynamic properties of those using some kind of expressions.

(for instance imagine a traffic light which consists of 3 separate lights but has only one data item associated. So it should be possible to define within the GUI some way which translates the value to a color of one of the sub components. Optimally it should be possible to parametrize the item names via some kind of expression, which would it make it more resilient to copy & paste errors if the items have a common naming schema)

The created GUI should be easy to integrate in a Eclipse RCP environment. Most solutions lack in some way or the other, either no abstraction of the datasource/items, no ability to set metadata on the symbols, or no way to promote value changes to the subcomponents in a easy way.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

I have came across (but never used) a product from [ILog](http://www.ilog.com/promotions/ppc/visu/genscada/). I expect that it won't be cheap.

Comment: it **is** not cheap ;-)

Answer (score 0):

In the meantime we implemented our own HMI framework. It is still pretty rough around the edges, but for most of our use cases it works just fine.

Have a look at Eclipse SCADA http://www.eclipse.org/eclipsescada